# c# convert canvas to base64 image

Tags: c#, asp.net, html5-canvas

```
<canvas id="colors_sketch"  width="500" height="200">
   <asp:Button id="submit_button" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" OnClick="getValue"/>

 protected void getValue(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var base64 = colors_sketch.ToString;   
 }
```

I want to convert the user *drawing* to *base64*, when I add `run = server` in `colors_sketch`, I fail to do the drawing. Any ideas how to do this?
I want save the *base64* into database when user clicks *Submit*.

Comment: canvas is a client side thing. asp.net and c# run on the server. you have to use javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Comment: @Abion47 how can  document.getElementById function in c# ? :D

Comment: @KyLim Like Daniel said, the canvas is client side and your C# is server side. You need to convert the canvas to an image using Javascript and then send it to your server.